# Does Jenkins PerfPublisher Plugin validates the xml file itself or file should be validated first and then provided to perf plugin?

Tags: python, xml, validation, jenkins

I have a XML file in which there is DTD validation required as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE item SYSTEM "C:/report.dtd">
<item>
    <text>Address</text>
    <data>
        Sample
    </data>
</item>
```

Now this xml is being generated from python script and have to be provided to the jenkins [perfplugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PerfPublisher+Plugin). so, i read that the xml file must be validated inorder to be used by perf plugin but my point is when the dtd information is already added to the top of xml does it validate itself or not ?

Does it make sense that i should make the validation of xml file first from within the python script and then provide the file to perf plugin or is it sufficient to pass the xml file containing dtd tag information to the plugin? So, please suggest. I read that to xml files can be validated from python using lxml but i have Python 2.5 and it does not support lxml. so, if i have to do with Python 2.5 how shall i validate it?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like although [PerfPublisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PerfPublisher+Plugin) requires report files to follow scheme specified by DTD [file](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/42468412/report.dtd?version=1&modificationDate=1262493971000), plug-in itself doesn't execute validation as it uses default SAX parser which by default does not check XML.

As for Python and DTD validation. It don't think there is good alternative to LXML bindings. Unless you are interested in writing your own implementation of xml [handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html#dtdhandler-objects).

Otherwise depending on your setup try using `xmllint` with `--valid` or `--dtdvalid` option.